# jcshell: Cannot init/open terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, jcop

I’m trying to develop a Java smart card recently. I have installed NXP JCOP Tools for Eclipse in Eclipse, but it still doesn’t work, and the error is reported as follows

```
-  /term "Remote|localhost:49328"
```

jcshell: Cannot init/open terminal: Failed to open [localhost:49328]: Connection refused: connect

- /card -a a000000003000000 -c com.ibm.jc.CardManager
  jcshell: Error code: -8 (Failed (no diagnosis))
  jcshell: Command failed: No ATR
  Unexpected error; aborting execution

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking the port?

Comment: There is no firewall, I tested it on a bare metal virtual machine